# Reading a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find

How do I connect to a Mongodb?

I am trying to read the contents of a collection called "student".

```
onsole.log("001");
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
console.log("002");
const uri = process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING;

const client = new MongoClient(uri);
console.log("003");
async function run() {
  console.log("004");
  client.connect();
  const db = client.db("blah")
  console.log("005");
  const results = db.student.find()
  console.log("006")
  console.log(results)
  console.log("007")
}
//call function
run()
```

This works to,

```
console.log("005");
```

But not,

```
console.log("006");
```

So there must be a problem with,

```
  const results = db.student.find()
```

But at https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-query-document-using-find.html it says to do it like this.

Thanks,

Comment: try using await before db.find().

Comment: Try calling `client.close()` in the end.

Comment: I tried both those thing but no luck. I get an error  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' Thanks

Comment: ...  const db = client.db("blah")
  console.log("005");
  await const results = db.student.find()
  console.log("006")
  console.log(results)
  console.log("007")
  client.close()

Comment: Have you tried `db.getCollection("student").find()`?

Comment: Also, use `await` before `client.connect()`.

Comment: Thanks I tried them and no luck still. It can't be so difficult to connect to a mongodb. Thanks